# Is there a way to use gem recommendable with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, recommendation-engine

I'm developing a Rails app and my database is Postgresql. I want to have some kind of recommendation engine and I ran into this gem [recommendable](https://github.com/davidcelis/recommendable), but it uses MongoDB. Is there a way to set it so I can use it with Postgresql?

Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly do you see the dependency on Mongo?

Comment: [here](https://github.com/davidcelis/recommendable/tree/master/lib/recommendable/orm), in mongo_mapper.rb and mongoid.rb. And it has it listed under requirements in Readme

Comment: Mongo isn't mentioned at all in the requirements of the README. Mongoid and MongoMapper are ORM's for Mongo. They're not requirements for the gem; you can use ActiveRecord with PostgreSQL.